# Having problems in retrieving data from Cloud Firestore in my Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Let me illustrate my problem first,

I have three collections in my cloud Firestore 'followers', 'posts' and 'timeline'.
(1) 'followers' contain all those user id's whom I am following
[image: followers collection]
(2) 'posts' contain all the information which the particular user has posted.
[image: posts collection]
(3) 'timeline' contain all the posts of the users whom I am following.
[image: timeline collection]

My problem is that how can I implement timeline collection in flutter ? I am not able to filter information which I want to include in my flutter App. I want help on this part.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a timeline like that on the firestore is probably something you don't want. Everytime a user makes a post you have to find all users that are following him and update their timeline too, which will result in a lot of duplicated information and wasted processing power.

You'll probably have better results if you "generate" the timeline inside the app for each user, e.g.: when the user signs in, you fetch all the posts (or maybe just the first 50 or something) of the users he's following

Comment: But this will increase the size of the app to large extend. Actually this was already in back of my mind but I was looking for some better approach.

Comment: There may be a better approach, but I'm not seeing it. It should be noted that fetching the posts in real time won't increase the size of the app per se because the fetch data will be only kept temporarly. You won't have performance problems either because you'd only be querrying the remote database.

Comment: Yes you are right but what about if user update the timeline by liking any post or commenting on any post. How do I reflect all these changes..??

Comment: I believe you'd have to query firestore for changes each time the user consulted his timeline. I believe this shouldn't be a problem because firebase on flutter takes care of caching data and watching for changes for you (it just happens internally).
Think about it like the questions feed here on stack overflow, the list of questions and number of likes is updated each time you refresh the page.